# React Router, passing props to chlid routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have a method based on some searching to pass my props into my child routes, however I am not sure this is the best approach. I am using redux as well, so I was considering using react-router-redux but i first wanted to see if it is possible without another library. So here is my currently working method:

My routes:

```
 <Router history={browserHistory} >
      <Route path="/" component={main.Component} services={services}>
        <Route path="/collections" component={mainContent.Component}>
          <Route path="/collections/:collection" component={productList.Component}>
            <Route path="/:sub-collection" component={productList.Component} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Route>
 </Router>
```

And then in the main.component I just have this -

```
 render() {
const prods = this.props.products;
const children = React.Children.map(this.props.children, function(child) {
  return React.cloneElement(child, {
    products: prods
  });
});

return (
  <div className="follain-products row">
    Main Content Area
    {children}
  </div>
);
```

}

And the same approach inside the productList.component to pass the props down to the /:sub-collection route. This works, however I am wondering if there is a better or cleaner way of doing this? I dug around a bunch and this cloneElment approach seems to be a common method. Thanks!

Comment: It seems this use case was one of the motivation for the `react-router` v4 rewrite. With v4, the API makes it easier to have nested routes.

See here this example : https://react-router.now.sh/recursive-paths